# How to check which file type has PrintTo command available in Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry

In Windows Explorer, when you right click, there is a 'Print' function for some of the file type.  I know it's using the vert PrintTo to print the file.

I want to know how can I identify does a specific file type has this PrintTo verb association?  Any available library in C#?

Comment: You could look through the registry

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verbs(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

The context menu from the windows explorer is build with the information from the registry => HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. Here you will find all registered extensions. For example **.txt**, under .txt you will find his **(Default)** => **txtfile**.

My Windows is german so whats called (Default) is here (Standard).

[image: Registry file type]

And when you look for the **txtfile** entry in the registry there will be txtfile=>shell=>print/printto. And if you don't find the shell=>print/printto entry, there also will be no print option in the context menu. There even is the print command which windwos will use to print your file. You can to this for every file type.

[image]

And to read from the registry there will be many example on the web like this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C

Comment: Demonstrates well that the print and printto verbs are not the same.  You highlighted the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I implement it in C# based on Momo's answer.

```
public static bool HasPrintToVerb(string filename)
{
    try
    {
        var ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);

        var value = Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\" + ext, string.Empty, null);
        var printToValue = Registry.GetValue(string.Format(@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\{0}\shell\Printto\command", value), string.Empty, null);
        return printToValue != null;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/ProcessStartInfo.cs,75bd50346bca44e3